# AWS ElasticBeanStalk Error

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to put a Django based WebApp using ElasticBeanStalk,However in the middle of deployment, I get that there is some error,Please check Log file.I searched the log file but cannot understand the error,Can anybody help me to understand what is happening?

```
Logs:
 * The following required packages can not be built:
 * freetype

      ----------------------------------------
  Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-n5etdtzo/matplotlib/
  2017-04-18 02:06:43,611 ERROR    Error installing dependencies: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 22, in main
      install_dependencies()
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 18, in install_dependencies
      check_call('%s install -r %s' % (os.path.join(APP_VIRTUAL_ENV, 'bin', 'pip'), requirements_file), shell=True)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 541, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1 (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
caused by: Requirement already satisfied: appdirs==1.4.3 in /opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 1))
  Requirement already satisfied: aws-requests-auth==0.3.0 in /opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 2))
  Collecting awscli==1.11.61 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 3))
    Using cached awscli-1.11.61-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting awsebcli==3.10.0 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 4))
    Using cached awsebcli-3.10.0.tar.gz
  Collecting backports.ssl-match-hostname==3.5.0.1 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 5))
    Using cached backports.ssl_match_hostname-3.5.0.1.tar.gz
  Collecting bdist-mpkg==0.5.0 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 6))
    Using cached bdist_mpkg-0.5.0.tar.gz
  Collecting blessed==1.14.1 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 7))
    Using cached blessed-1.14.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Requirement already satisfied: boto3==1.4.4 in /opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 8))
  Collecting botocore==1.5.24 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 9))
    Using cached botocore-1.5.24-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting cement==2.8.2 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 10))
    Using cached cement-2.8.2.tar.gz
  Collecting colorama==0.3.7 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 11))
    Using cached colorama-0.3.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Requirement already satisfied: Django==1.10.6 in /opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 12))
  Collecting django-extensions==1.7.7 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 13))
    Using cached django_extensions-1.7.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting django-extensions-shell==1.7.4.1 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 14))
    Using cached django_extensions_shell-1.7.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting docker-py==1.7.2 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 15))
    Using cached docker-py-1.7.2.tar.gz
  Collecting dockerpty==0.4.1 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 16))
    Using cached dockerpty-0.4.1.tar.gz
  Collecting docopt==0.6.2 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 17))
    Using cached docopt-0.6.2.tar.gz
  Requirement already satisfied: docutils==0.13.1 in /opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 18))
  Collecting elasticsearch==5.2.0 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 19))
    Using cached elasticsearch-5.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting futures==3.0.5 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 20))
    Using cached futures-3.0.5.tar.gz
  Requirement already satisfied: jmespath==0.9.2 in /opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 21))
  Collecting macholib==1.5.1 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 22))
    Using cached macholib-1.5.1.tar.gz
  Collecting matplotlib==1.3.1 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 23))
    Using cached matplotlib-1.3.1.tar.gz
      Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
      ============================================================================
      Edit setup.cfg to change the build options

      BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
                  matplotlib: yes [1.3.1]
                      python: yes [3.4.3 (default, Sep  1 2016, 23:33:38)  [GCC
                              4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9)]]
                    platform: yes [linux]

      REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
                       numpy: yes [not found. pip may install it below.]
                    dateutil: yes [using dateutil version 2.6.0]
                     tornado: yes [tornado was not found. It is required for the
                              WebAgg backend. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                              install it after matplotlib.]
                   pyparsing: yes [using pyparsing version 2.2.0]
                       pycxx: yes [Official versions of PyCXX are not compatible
                              with Python 3.x.  Using local copy]
                      libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                              be found. Using local copy.]
                    freetype: no  [pkg-config information for 'freetype2' could
                              not be found.]
                         png: yes [pkg-config information for 'libpng' could not
                              be found. Using unknown version.]

      OPTIONAL SUBPACKAGES
                 sample_data: yes [installing]
                    toolkits: yes [installing]
                       tests: yes [nose 0.11.1 or later is required to run the
                              matplotlib test suite]

      OPTIONAL BACKEND EXTENSIONS
                      macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]
                      qt4agg: no  [PyQt4 not found]
                     gtk3agg: no  [gtk3agg backend does not work on Python 3]
                   gtk3cairo: no  [Requires cairo to be installed.]
                      gtkagg: no  [Requires pygtk]
                       tkagg: no  [TKAgg requires Tkinter.]
                       wxagg: no  [requires wxPython]
                         gtk: no  [Requires pygtk]
                         agg: yes [installing]
                       cairo: no  [cairo not found]
                   windowing: no  [Microsoft Windows only]

      OPTIONAL LATEX DEPENDENCIES
                      dvipng: no
                 ghostscript: no
                       latex: no
                     pdftops: no

      ============================================================================
                              * The following required packages can not be built:
                              * freetype

      ----------------------------------------
  Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-n5etdtzo/matplotlib/
  2017-04-18 02:06:43,611 ERROR    Error installing dependencies: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 22, in main
      install_dependencies()
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 18, in install_dependencies
      check_call('%s install -r %s' % (os.path.join(APP_VIRTUAL_ENV, 'bin', 'pip'), requirements_file), shell=True)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 541, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1 (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)


[2017-04-18T02:06:43.630Z] INFO  [3334]  - [Application update 7@5/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/03deploy.py] : Activity failed.
[2017-04-18T02:06:43.630Z] INFO  [3334]  - [Application update 7@5/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook] : Activity failed.
[2017-04-18T02:06:43.630Z] INFO  [3334]  - [Application update 7@5/AppDeployStage0] : Activity failed.
[2017-04-18T02:06:43.631Z] INFO  [3334]  - [Application update 7@5] : Completed activity. Result:
  Application update - Command CMD-AppDeploy failed
[2017-04-18T02:07:43.802Z] INFO  [3482]  - [CMD-BundleLogs] : Starting activity...
[2017-04-18T02:07:43.802Z] INFO  [3482]  - [CMD-BundleLogs/AddonsBefore] : Starting activity...
[2017-04-18T02:07:43.802Z] INFO  [3482]  - [CMD-BundleLogs/AddonsBefore] : Completed activity.
[2017-04-18T02:07:43.803Z] INFO  [3482]  - [CMD-BundleLogs/BundleLogs] : Starting activity...
[2017-04-18T02:07:43.803Z] INFO  [3482]  - [CMD-BundleLogs/BundleLogs/BundleLogs] : Starting activity...



My requirements.txt file is
appdirs==1.4.3
aws-requests-auth==0.3.0
awscli==1.11.61
awsebcli==3.10.0
backports.ssl-match-hostname==3.5.0.1
bdist-mpkg==0.5.0
blessed==1.14.1
boto3==1.4.4
botocore==1.5.24
cement==2.8.2
colorama==0.3.7
Django==1.10.6
django-extensions==1.7.7
django-extensions-shell==1.7.4.1
docker-py==1.7.2
dockerpty==0.4.1
docopt==0.6.2
docutils==0.13.1
elasticsearch==5.2.0
futures==3.0.5
jmespath==0.9.2
macholib==1.5.1
matplotlib==1.3.1
modulegraph==0.10.4
numpy==1.8.0rc1
oauthlib==2.0.1
packaging==16.8
pathspec==0.5.0
py2app==0.7.3
pyasn1==0.2.3
pyparsing==2.2.0
pysolr==3.6.0
python-dateutil==2.6.0
pytz==2013.7
PyYAML==3.12
requests==2.9.1
requests-oauthlib==0.8.0
rsa==3.4.2
s3transfer==0.1.10
scipy==0.13.0b1
semantic-version==2.5.0
six==1.10.0
tabulate==0.7.5
termcolor==1.1.0
tweepy==3.5.0
urllib3==1.20
vboxapi==1.0
virtualenv==15.1.0
watson-developer-cloud==0.25.2
wcwidth==0.1.7
websocket-client==0.40.0
xattr==0.6.4
zope.interface==4.1.1
```

I am using Pycharm for the development but used pip freeze command to generate these requirements.

Update1: I removed some requirements and it deployed successfully but I am getting Server 500 error when trying to access the webapp from the link.

Answer (score 0):

Elastic Beanstalk is trying to install your requirements.txt items one by one, but it stops at "egg_info". Here is the error:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-n5etdtzo/matplotlib/
```

I'm guessing that you are not using a virtual environment for your local development. That's why you see all unnecessary items in your requirements.txt :

You have two options:

1. Try installing (or removing) the ones that run into error manually on your instance  (one by one after each failed deployment). To do this, you have to connect to your EC2 directly and then `pip install` or maybe `sudo pip install` them. You will probably have to repeat the process a few times.
2. (Cannot switch to this method soon enough) Create a simple virtualenv and pick the requirements that are REALLY needed and then try your deployment again.

To create new environment:

```
cd my_app

virtualenv .
```

Activate the env:

```
source bin/activate
```

create new requirement.txt

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

add only the NECESSARY items to it, and done!